# How to add background color only to main element and not :before and :after

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a heading to look like this:

[image]

The issue is that when I try to add a background color to the h2, it applies to the :before and :after content as well and spans the width of the page. I only want it applied to the h2.

I've tried adding a div inside the h2 and styling that instead of the h2.

```css
.styled-heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.styled-heading:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0px 8px 0;
  background-color: #999;
  height: 3px;
  width: 140px;
}

.styled-heading:after {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 8px 00px;
  background-color: #999;
  height: 3px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="styled-heading">Testing Testing</h2>
```

Comment: The background colour *does not* apply to `::before` and `::after`. They are just inside the `h2` which (because it is `display: block`) spans the width of its parent element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this differently without pseudo element:

```css
.styled-heading {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  display:table; /* to make the element fit the content */
  margin:auto;  /* to center */
  /* The border will be the space for the lines*/
  border-left:50px solid transparent;
  border-right:50px solid transparent;
  
  padding:5px 10px;
  background:
     /* main background cover only the padding*/
    linear-gradient(green,green) padding-box,
    /* the Line cover also the border area (width:100% height:3px)*/
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) center/100% 3px border-box no-repeat; 
}
```

```html
<h2 class="styled-heading">Testing Testing</h2>
```

You can also have each line alone if you want:

```css
.styled-heading {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  display:table; /* to make the element fit the content */
  margin:auto;  /* to center */
  /* The border will be the space for the lines*/
  border-left:50px solid transparent;
  border-right:50px solid transparent;
  
  padding:5px 10px;
  background:
     /* main background cover only the padding*/
    linear-gradient(green,green) padding-box,
    /* the Line cover also the border area*/
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) left  center/50% 3px border-box no-repeat, 
    linear-gradient(red,red)   right center/50% 3px border-box no-repeat; 
}
```

```html
<h2 class="styled-heading">Testing Testing</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks Temani! This is exactly what I was looking for. I tried replacing the linear-gradient with just "black" but it didn't work. Do I need to use linear gradient or can I just use a solid color?

Comment: @cjk47 you have to use gradient, but since I am specifying the same color it's like using solid color but all the trick rely on gradient

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo element is not the way to do this. Pseudo elements are part of the element. This works:

```css
.header-pinch {
 position: relative;
 height: 3px;
 width: 500px;
 z-index: 1;
 overflow: visible;
 background: grey;
}
.header-pop {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 background: black;
 color: white;
 width: fit-content;
 padding: 5px;
        margin: auto;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<br/>
<div class="header-pinch">
<h2 class="header-pop">TESTING</h2>
</div>
```